# Git alias for commit with message including part of branch name

Tags: git

I am trying to write git alias, which would create commit with message including given parameter and part of a branch name. For example I am on the branch `feature/my-branch`, so the commit message should look like this:

```
feature: given message

- my-branch
```

So far I was able to come up with this:

```
feat = "!myF() { git commit -m \"feature: $1\n - $(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD) \" ; }; myF "
```

What I cannot achieve is to remove `feature/` from the branch name (it will always be there). I tried bash replace feature, but it requires variable, which I don't know how to create in git alias syntax, and sed command, but that requires input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple commands in your alias function.

```bash
name="$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"
echo ${name#feature/}  # removes any feature/ prefix
```

So your alias:

`feat = "!myF() { name=\"$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)\"; git commit -m \"feature: $1\n - ${name#feature/} \" ; }; myF "`